# Division and group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, cyclic-groups, cryptography

Say we have these following parameters,

> q : A k-bit prime
>
> $F_q$ : A prime finite field
>
> $E/F_q$ : An elliptic curve E over $F_q$
>
> G : A cyclic additive group of composite order q
>
> P : A generator for group G
>
> s : A secret key of trusted authority center
>
> $PK_{TAC}$ : A public key of the trusted authority center,
> $PK_{TAC}=sP$

Now, I want to obtain $s$  from the equation $PK_{TAC}=sP$, can I simple solve it like $s=\dfrac{PK_{TAC}}{P}.$

I asked my instructor about this, what she told is that elliptic curve is a discrete log problem so we cant do it, but I am not getting how elliptic curve is even related to that equation.
Any help will be really great. Thank you.

Comment: What does “composite order $q$” mean when $q$ is prime - aka not composite.

Comment: is this a mistake or have they done it intentionally?

Comment: Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: @Turing101 No idea, it’s your question, you have the context and full text, I don’t.

Comment: The elliptic curve is related to the equation since the group structure of $G$ is addition of points on the elliptic curve $E$ (and $sP = P \oplus P \oplus \ldots \oplus P$ ($s$ times)).

Comment: @Rushy Ok, thanks a lot.. :)